# StacktraceElement with timestamp

Tags: java, multithreading, stack-trace

StackTrace gives class, method, line number in source file.

Is there a way to get the time stamp at which the method executed as well?

Comment: Adding timestamps would make each method call 10x slower or more.  Why do you need to know this?

Comment: This will give us an idea on 1. Order of execution 2. time taken between calls

Comment: The order of execution is defined by the order of the stack.  You don't need to timestamp these.  The time taken between calls is usually more useful for calls at the same level.  If you want to timestamp different stages of you application, I have a enum of timestamp phases and add a timestamp to an array of long when that phase is reached.  AT the end I analyse this to see what the histogram of timings was to see where the longest delays are occurring.

Answer (score 2):

I don't thnik so since the API doesn't give you access to a timestamp. Neither the `Exception` nor the `StatckTraceElement` API.

You can use logging (e.g. wtih log4j) and log the exception. A log record can print out the timestamp of the log record. Of cource this is the timestamp when the record was logged and not when
the exception ocurred, but if you log immediatly after an exception it should not
make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

JVM does not keep track when a statement is executed. Hence stack trace will not have that information.  You can modify your java code to have such a feature.  Here is product you should try- [Chronon Time travelling debugger.](http://chrononsystems.com/products/chronon-time-travelling-debugger)  (I never used it, though)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get time stamp from `StackTrace`.
You can use [java.util.logging](http://tutorialswithexamples.com/java-logging-configuration-using-properties-file/) api or [log4j](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/).
Choose one of them based on your application requirement.
Please look into
[java.util.logging vs log4j](http://java.sys-con.com/node/48541)